# onResume() update TextView

Tags: java, android, onresume

I have my main depotactivity where he sets integer value to a textview, now I want this value to get updated when onResume() is called... but when I add my little onResume() code

```
public class DepotActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DepotDBUtils utils = new DepotDBUtils(this);
        int itemcount = utils.countItems(this);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);
        tv.setText(tv.getText()+" "+itemcount);
    }
   String TAG = "DepotActivity";
   String[] itemInfo;
 public void onResume(){
    Log.d("DepotActivity","onResume() gets called");
    DepotDBUtils utils = new DepotDBUtils(this);
    int itemcount = utils.countItems(this);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);
    tv.setText(tv.getText()+" "+itemcount);
    }
```

to the app I can't even start it, and LogCat gets totally crazy and doesn't log any activity for more than half a second. Any solutions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Notice that onResume gets called even the first time the Activity is created, so there is no need to copy the code in onCreate and onResume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with adding `super.onResume();`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // The rest
}
```

I would also remove that:

```
    DepotDBUtils utils = new DepotDBUtils(this);
    int itemcount = utils.countItems(this);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);
    tv.setText(tv.getText()+" "+itemcount);
```

from `onCreate`, since every time `onCreate` is called, `onResume` is called as well.

Comment: Also add `@Override` to `onRexume()` and change from `public` to `protected`

Comment: Thanks! ( I can only accept your answer in 3 minutes.. dunno why, but I'll do it) 
Thanks too for the additional tipp, cleaning up my code now :) and taking a second look at the android lifecycle lol